# Custom Sort Maps in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I have a list of maps like below. I want to sort the maps inside the list in custom order in Java 8.

For Example, Below is the list of maps .

```
[{model=Ferrari},
{model=Tesla},
{model=Benz},
{model=Honda}]
```

If I sort the above list of maps using the below code, Its sorting in Alphabetical order.

```
l.sort(Comparator.comparing((Map<String,String> mp) -> mp.get("model")));
```

gives the output below.

> [{model=Benz}, {model=Ferrari}, {model=Honda}, {model=Tesla}]

But I need to sort this map based on the order(Not Alphabetical Order) :  **Honda,Tesla,Benz, Ferrari**

Is there a better approach we can achieve the custom sort in Java 8 ?

Comment: If you want a custom order, it has to be defined somewhere. You can, for example, add a second entry into each of your maps, "order=1" or something.

Comment: If you put `["Honda", "Tesla", "Benz", "Ferrari"]` in a list, you can sort by the model's index in that list.

Comment: @khelwood thats good idea. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: what if there are 5 or models how you can sort them, what logic you base?

Comment: @YCF_L The models are just placeholders. I have an requirement to sort based on 4 values only. But it will be good if I get the generic solution.

Comment: Highly not recommended, but you could sort based on `mp.get("model").hashCode() % 17` in this example, if you change the values you'd need a different mod/equation ("Honda"->1, "Tesla"->6, "Benz"->7, "Ferrari"->12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define your preferred order somewhere outside of this code. Put it into some kind of list and then transform it to Map of modelName -> index.

```
Map<String,Integer> modelOrder = .....
```

then, you can add one more lookup for getting ordinal for comparison.

```
l.sort(Comparator.comparing((Map<String,String> mp) ->
    modelOrder.get(mp.get("model"))));
```

This will explode in your face if unknown model is ever encountered. You can do quick fix by something like

```
l.sort(Comparator.comparing((Map<String,String> mp) -> 
    modelOrder.getOrDefault(mp.get("model"),Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
```

to put unknown models at the very end, but they won't be sorted between themselves (so even same unknown model might be interlaced by other unknown ones).

Edit:

As people suggested in comments, it can be solved nicely with .thenComparing

```
l.sort(Comparator
    .comparing((Map<String,String> mp) -> modelOrder.getOrDefault(mp.get("model"),Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    .thenComparing((Map<String,String> mp) -> mp.get("model")));
```

Comment: Should be able to use something like `(long)(Math.abs(mp.get("model").hashCode())) + modelOrder.size()` as the default value to sort the unknowns.  The use of long is to prevent overflows from the hashcode, and modelOrder.size() should ensure it's after the known models.  Overall this might be a bit overkill

Comment: Or just use `thenComparing(modelOrder.get(mp.get("model"))` to compare the strings if they are not in the list (after comparing the `getOrDefault()`).

Comment: @Didier L: you can avoid doing an additional map lookup, `Comparator.comparing(mp -> mp.get("model"), Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> modelOrder.getOrDefault( s,Integer.MAX_VALUE)) .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))`